# Gradle build fails looking for Google Play Services in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I'm trying to run my project in Android Studio 0.3.6, but I always get this error :

```
Gradle: A problem occurred configuring root project 'myapp_android'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_DebugCompile'.
  > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36.
    Required by:
        :myapp_android:unspecified
     > Could not GET 'http://maven.hq.couchbase.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/google/android/gms/play-services/3.1.36/play-services-3.1.36.pom'. Received status code 503 from server: Service Temporarily Unavailable
```

Here is my complete `build.gradle` file :

```
home = System.getenv("ANDROID_HOME")

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "http://maven.hq.couchbase.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/"
    }

    maven {
        url "http://files.couchbase.com/maven2/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36'
    compile 'com.couchbase.cblite:CBLite:1.0.0-beta'
    compile 'com.couchbase.cblite:CBLiteEktorp:1.0.0-beta'
    compile 'com.couchbase.cblite:CBLiteJavascript:1.0.0-beta'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

    instrumentTestCompile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:4.3'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.1"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}

tasks.withType(Compile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```

And finally, my SDK Manager :

[image: Android SDK Manager]

I tried with many versions of Android Studio (0.2.8, 0.2.9, 0.2.13, 0.3.2, 0.3.6) and it's always the same. I tried changing the Play Services version, I tried changing the order of the dependencies, nothing did the trick.

Is there something not correct with my setup? I looked for answers and pretty much everything I found (`build.gradle` structure, SDK missing items) was already fine...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally found what was the problem. @gnuf pointed me in the right direction. But the problem was that Android Studio, in Project Structure | Platform Settings | Android SDK, showed the wrong SDK. It showed the SDK it used was `C:/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-studio/sdk`, but in fact, I discovered it tried to build with another SDK located in `C:\Users\my_username\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk`.

Needless to say, it didn't work. There was nothing installed in this SDK. So I copied the contents of `C:/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-studio/sdk` to `C:\Users\my_username\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk` and **it worked**! My first build in three weeks.

So I think it's a bug of Android Studio. If anyone runs into this problem, make sure you only have one SDK on your computer. If you have more than one, make sure they all have the required dependencies. If you can, just copy the content of the most up to date to the others.

Comment: It's not a bug so much as something that isn't clearly documented. Android Studio bundles its own copy of the SDK which it uses by default. You can just point Android Studio to the copy installed via the Android SDK Manager.

Answer (score 2):

It may be the case that the location where you've installed the SDK components is different than the one that Android Studio is using.

Can you verify that the local Maven repositories (installed by the Google Repository and Android Support Repository) are under the Android SDK that you're using in your Android Studio project?

In Android Studio, go to Project Structure | Platform Settings | Android SDK. (On my machine, the path for Android SDK Location is `/opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/android-sdk/22.2.1` ) In that directory, ensure that the subdirectory `extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services/` exists.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm this. The SDK patch in Project Structure | Platform Settings | Android SDK is `C:/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-studio/sdk` (yeah I'm on Windows) and the directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\play-services\3.1.36`exists.

Answer (score -1):

It looks for Google dependencies like Google Play Services in your SDK extras, not in Maven repositories over the network. Install the "Google Repository" in your SDK manager and you should be good to go.

Comment: Didn't you see the screenshot of my SDK Manager I added in my post?