# Gradle build fails looking for Google Play Services in Android Studio - is my SDK correct?

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-gradle-plugin

I have a question very similar to [Gradle build fails looking for Google Play Services in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20198502/gradle-build-fails-looking-for-google-play-services-in-android-studio)

I have a working android project but when I add

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77'
```

I get a gradle build error

```
Error:Failed to find: com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.2.8
<a href="openFile">Open File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Open in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

I have added the SDKs through the manager. Other threads have suggested that there might be a second SDK library on the computer causing the issue, but I have not been able to resolve this. I am using a mac (and normally a PC user so please bear with me) and looking at the SDK manager and the project structure dialog both say the SDK is located at:

```
/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk
```

Given they are pointing to the same place it must be some other cause of the error?

Maybe I have a version other than 5.2.8 (although unlikely, as andoid studio says this is the most up to date and I have just updated the SDK)? How can I check the version installed on my machine - its not in the file names?

Comment: Well, this error here `Error:Failed to find: com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.2.8` tells you that you have the wrong version defined.

Comment: Or that I have the right version in the wrong place on my system which I thought was more likely given my SDK manager says I have the latest version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK so it looks as though my version number was off and thats all that was causing the problem. If anyone else has this issue check your version number in the AndroidManifest.xml file in the google_play_services_lib directory

Comment: Works for me, this actually happen to me when I try to develop in another machine.

Answer (score 7):

If you are going to use version 5.2.8 you have to set on your build.gradle

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.2.08'
```

Because it is store on the directory :

ANDROID_SDK_PATH/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services/5.2.08

You can use '+' instead '08' and you will be using the last minor version

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.2.+'
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a problem with the `5.0.77` release version. Change `com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77` to `com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89` and things will work fine.

Google pulled out `5.0.77` from the Maven repository due to some critical bugs. [Read More.](http://tools.android.com/knownissues)

Answer (score 0):

I had a different problem altogether. I'd put the line

> apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

at the start of the file. Even before:

> apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

And had to scratch my head for half an hour.

So the final (working) condition looked like:

> apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
>
> apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'